# File upload with streaming or in chunks

Tags: spring-boot, streaming, multipartform-data, filestream, httpbrowsercapabilities

I need to understand when I click on submit button with form data for a file with some other data , what happens.

Scenario is we have couple of layers (apigee, Nginx) where it restricts requests size with 2 mb.

And I have fille more than 1GB to upload.

I need to understand if in the browser is the file uploaded as a whole, meaning reading from input stream ,writing at server side from stream as it comes solution will not work.

Or is the multi part file uploaded in chunks , if so can I define  chunk size at client side (html/ui code)
If this is automatically done internally over http connection, I can simply use streaming. But if it has to be broken in chunks, can someone please advise.